# Confirm box before closing active chat window

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a chat window in which user can ask for support on my website.
The thing is , after he's done and wants to close the window , he presses an 'X' which closes the chat window. 
But I did a div here which appears in the middle of the screen and asks him if he wants to really close the windows or not.
Here is the code :

```
<div id="background">
<div id="stay">
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:19px;margin-top:10px;">Exiting the support window will delete all the conversation you had with the staff and will disconnect you from the conversation. </p>
<p style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:19px;">Are you sure you want to exit ?</p>
<div id="agree">
<p>Yes</p>
</div>
<div id="cancel">
<p>No</p>
</div>
</div><!--stay end-->
</div><!--background end-->
```

Jquery :

```
$("#exit").click(function() {
        $("#livesupport").hide();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
        $("#background").toggle();
        $("body").css({ 'overflow':'hidden' });
        $.post('utility/rchat.php', { table: sessid } , 
        function(getshiton) {
        });
});
```

"#livesupport" is the chat window.

How do I make No an answer so when the user presses it it return back to the page and no changes made to the page , and when he presses Yes he gets to have the support window closed.

Comment: Am a little confused - what is your problem. I might be misreading but couldn't find a question in there?

Comment: Why not just use a real confirm box, and based on the selection(presented as true/false) perform your actions?

Comment: oh .... i'm so retarded :))) sorry I will edit it .

Comment: I don't want to use the real confirm box because it looks awful , the box that I did is more styled.

Comment: You can call the function closing the window **after** user confirms he wants to leave the chat, when he clicks to stay, nothing will happen this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of what you're doing with yes and no, I would use a popup box, it's pretty easy to do.
Your code would look like this:

```
$("#exit").click(function() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to exit this window?")) {
        $("#livesupport").hide();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
        $("#background").toggle();
        $("body").css({ 'overflow':'hidden' });
        $.post('utility/rchat.php', { table: sessid } , 
        function(getshiton) {
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is indeed a good answer , but the popup box doesn't have the style that I want , my popup box is more styled .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're all working with here, but here's a basic concept.  Your custom "confirm" message box will have two buttons and is hidden by default.

```
// USER CLICKED THE EXIT BUTTON
$("#exit").click(function() {
    /*  SHOW YOUR CUSTOM CONFIRM OVERLAY */
}

// CONFIRM BUTTON IS CLICKED
$("#confirmExitButton").click(function(){
   /* CLOSE THE CHAT */
});

//CANCEL BUTTON IS CLICKED
$("#cancelExitButton").click(function(){
   /* MAKE THE CONFIRM DISAPEAR */
});
```